# Setting up client Google Tasks App

Tags: java, dependencies, google-api-java-client, scribe, google-tasks-api

**My Question:** How do I properly setup the Google Tasks client library api so I can build my app? (i.e. this may be just a dependency problem due to poor documentation).

**The problem:** Google Tasks has unfortunate lower support so the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/instantiate) on this is out of date (their code doesn't compile with the dependencies they give). I'm missing the following necessary classes:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl;
```

I can't seem to find `*.draft10.*;`. It is (they are) not contained in any of the dependencies Google gives in the [documentation for setup](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/setup).

I'm actually guessing that the problem isn't with the client library they provide, but the setup code example they give.

I thought about just hitting the REST service using [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to authenticate instead, but I faced some challenges there as well and I think it would be a lot easier to just figure out this problem.

**Note:** My app is a client application. It's for personal development and enjoyment. It will probably have a really simple swing interface. I'm not doing anything on Android or in a web app.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the Tasks documentation being so out of date!  We do have two updated examples for the google-api-java-client that may be of help to you:

[calendar-cmdline-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) demonstrates how to do the OAuth 2.0 flow

[tasks-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html) demonstrates working with the Tasks API

NOTE: I'm an owner of google-api-java-client project

Comment: Hopefully this points someone in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Both links are invalid now... Any up to date examples / docs for oauth2 currently?